# Fixed text scrolling within a container div

Tags: html, css, scroll, position

I'm developing an html and css page, and I'm having trouble trying to leave the text fixed while I scroll the page.

I have 3 divs, where each one has its h1 title.

Is it possible to scroll the pages, leaving the titles in a fixed position while the div moves?

```css
.corpo{
  width:80%px;
  height:1200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin:20px;
  margin-bottom:50px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="corpo">
  <h1> Title 1</h1>
</div>

<div class="corpo">
  <h1> Title 2</h1>
</div>

<div class="corpo">
  <h1> Title 3</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, the h1 tag would be fixed until you get to the next h1 tag where it would then be fixed

Comment: I'm seeing some tutorials to try to create this with js or css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way to achieve what you are looking for is to use `position: sticky` and specify `top` depending on where you want the `h1` to stick relative to the container `div`. See snippet below for an example:

```css
.corpo {
  width: 80%;
  height: 1200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;  
}

.corpo h1 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="corpo">
  <h1> Title 1</h1>
</div>

<div class="corpo">
  <h1> Title 2</h1>
</div>

<div class="corpo">
  <h1> Title 3</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not know of the existence of this sticky, it will work perfectly for me. but what is the difference between it and the fixed?

Comment: You can find a detailed description of both `fixed` and `sticky` here: [css position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)